# How can i generate SQL DEMO online temporarily base ?

Tags: discussion, sql, database

I have some query in SQL data retrieving  related so how can i display in stackoverflow, 
any one know me.
please .

Comment: [**http://sqlfiddle.com/**](http://sqlfiddle.com/) just build schema and paste in your question

Comment: This is probably better on meta .. in any case, make sure that you *also* post the relevant SQL/data/output in the post.

Comment: Your schema ddl is too large (more than 8000 characters).  Please submit a smaller DDL.  i got this error mr. @MKhalidJunaid you have other website for larger data upload online ...

Comment: Huh... this doesn't look like a question for meta - or for SO main either. I don't really even understand the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is what you need I think:

http://sqlfiddle.com/

Comment: Beat me to it by a few seconds!

Comment: but they not given more data save they only save 8000 Words , any other options sir @wribit

Comment: @ChiragPipariya Perhaps the "DEMO" is too big then? *I* wouldn't want to read it if it was > 8000 words.

Comment: i got this error "Your schema ddl is too large (more than 8000 characters).  Please submit a smaller DDL." any other website for sql . @user2864740

Comment: I don't know of anything online that would support that big a file... sorry Chirag

Comment: if find any thing so please tell me sir @wribit  thank you